# xcode 4.5 wont let me debug on ios 5.1 device

Tags: ios, xcode4

I recently got a new dev machine and downloaded the latest xcode 4.5. It came with IOS 6 only so I went and got sdk 5.0 and 5.1 from older xcodes.

The device im testing on in running ios 5.1 and I'd like to keep it that way for the moment.

In my project settings I have base sdk set to ios 5.1.

The trouble is that when I try to debug on my ios 5.1 device xcode complains that I need to connect an iOS device with a recent enough version of iOS to run my application.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Newer versions of Xcode only let you test using devices capable of iOS 16.0 or later. Please head to the nearest Apple Store and buy the most recent and most expensive iDevice.

Comment: Despite setting my base sdk?!?

Comment: Try to download extra ios simulators called components from preferences -> download and select component and click on check and install now button

Comment: @Wolvorin. Yeah I have IOS5 simulator but I want to test on device

Comment: Have you clicked on the button in right side upper corner and if you have all components updated then check for the device is registered for development use :)

Answer (score 1):

You can surely run your app on a iOS 5.1 device when using Xcode 4.5 - I am doing that at the very present moment.

Have you checked in Xcode organizer if your device is configured for development? Go to the Organizer (one of the top-left icons), select your device from the lefthand list and click on "use for development" (if available).

Hope this helps.

Comment: I dont see the "use for development" option but I have being using it for development before.

Answer (score 1):

I have xCode 4.5 like you and I have an iPod Touch 3G 5.1.1 which works perfectly with iOS 6 SDK.
The SDK Number doesn't tell you that it only works for that firmware.
In your Project settings under targets you can define the sdk, not the sdk you build with(this is 6.0) but youcan tell what the minOS is

Answer (score 1):

Try restarting with your 5.1 device plugged in.

My iPod 5.1.1 is provisioned and has been used for development.  If I choose the scheme "iOS Device" Xcode 4.5.2 refuses to run, telling me "Xcode cannot run using selected device".  However it does work when I set the scheme to "robert's iPod" (or whatever).  This choice doesn't show up right away when I plug the device in, and sometimes I seem to need to quit and restart Xcode and/or iTunes (or reboot) in order to see it.